# search and delete a shortcut

Tags: c#, visual-studio

the project i am working on has to run on the windows startup i found the code, but what if the user don't wan't it to start on the startup!, do i have to tell the user to search for the sortcut and delete it, or simply make a button for that option, i know how to delete the file like this:

```
if(File.Exists(@"C:\Users\Maged\Desktop\remainder\WindowsFormsApplication1\bin\Debug\WindowsFormsApplication1.exe"))
{
    File.Delete(@"C:\Users\Maged\Desktop\remainder\WindowsFormsApplication1\bin\Debug\WindowsFormsApplication1.exe");
}
```

i need to make the program searsh for `MyStartupShortcut.lnk` and delete it if exists.

here is my code on creating the shortcut:

```
void CreateStartupShortcut()
{
    string startupFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Startup);
    WshShell shell = new WshShell();
    string shortcutAddress = startupFolder + @"\MyStartupShortcut.lnk";
    IWshShortcut shortcut = (IWshShortcut)shell.CreateShortcut(shortcutAddress);
    shortcut.Description = "A startup shortcut. If you delete this shortcut from your computer, LaunchOnStartup.exe will not launch on Windows Startup";
    shortcut.WorkingDirectory = Application.StartupPath; 
    shortcut.TargetPath = Application.ExecutablePath;
    shortcut.Save();
}
```

i need to delete this file no matter the director is, any help?

Comment: As you know how the shortcut was created, and you show code for that, you know where the shortcut is located - see the `shortcutAddress` in the code. Hence deleting it should be easy. The code shown at the top of the question deletes an executable, nota shortcut and so seems irrelevant to the problem of deleting the shortcut.

Comment: i know where the shortcut is located, but when the user will run it, it will change based on his Machine so i need to make a search and delete that shortcut for him

Comment: i think i get your point on `shortcutAddress`location, so how to preform Delete using that location

Comment: Will `if(File.Exists(shortcutAddress )) { File.Delete(shortcutAddress ); }` work? That is based on your own code from the top of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `shortcutAddress` created as in the `CreateStartupShortcut` method the deletion of the shortcut should be achieved with the code:

```
if ( File.Exists(shortcutAddress) )
{
    File.Delete(shortcutAddress );
}
```